# How can I convert a Long value to date time and convert current time to Long kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

The Code A can convert a long value to date value, just like 2018.01.10

1. I hope to get Date + Time value , such as 2018.01.10 23:11, how can I do with Kotlin?
2. I hope to convert current time to a long value , how can I do with Kotlin?

Thanks!

**Code A**

```
fun Long.toDateString(dateFormat: Int =  DateFormat.MEDIUM): String {
    val df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(dateFormat, Locale.getDefault())
    return df.format(this)
}
```

Comment: Use `SimpleDateFormat` https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Thanks! can you show some code with Kotlin?

Comment: I could if I had time, but it is quite easy to convert code from JAva

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I strongly recommend *against* `SimpleDateFormat`. That class was notoriously troublesome and is fortunately long outdated. Use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Comment: `return Instant.ofEpochMilli(this) .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()) .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(dateFormat));` where the `dateFormat` parameter should have type `FormatStyle` with possible values SHORT, MEDIUM, LONG and FULL

Comment: @OleV.V. necroposting at it's finest. It's fine, only 5 years has passed.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Try this, I use SimpleDataFormat.

```
fun convertLongToTime(time: Long): String {
    val date = Date(time)
    val format = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm")
    return format.format(date)
}

fun currentTimeToLong(): Long {
    return System.currentTimeMillis()
}

fun convertDateToLong(date: String): Long {
    val df = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm")
    return df.parse(date).time
}
```

And to convert java file to kotlin file with Android Studio, choosing `Code->Convert java file to kotlin file.`

Answer (score 8):

No need for anything complex:

Get current time and date as a `Date` object

```
val dateTime: Date = Calendar.getInstance().time
```

Convert it to a `Long`

```
val dateTimeAsLong: Long = dateTime.time
```

Convert that `Long` back to a `Date`

```
val backToDate: Date = Date(dateTimeAsLong)
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to use extension functions, as so...

Convert long to Time & Date String:

```
fun Long.toTimeDateString(): String {
    val dateTime = java.util.Date(this)
    val format = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.US)
    return format.format(dateTime)
}
```

Convert Time & Date String to Long:

```
fun String.toTimeDateLong(): Long {
    val format = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.US)
    return format.parse(this)?.time ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid time string")
}
```

To use:

```
fun main() {
   val timeDateLong = "10:23:12 12/11/2022".toTimeDateLong()
   
   val timeDateStr = timeDateLong.toTimeDateString()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert long to Date String with the format:

```
fun Long.convertMilliSecondsToDate(): String {
            val date = Date(this)
            val format = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH)
            return format.format(date)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private val simpleDateFormat by lazy { SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()) }

fun getDate(timeStamp: Long): String {
    return simpleDateFormat.format(Date(timeStamp))
}
```

Comment: This answer is in the 'low quality answers queue"